Props are passed but I can't access them
So in the Inspect tool I can see the props coming in just fine, but when i try to console log them i get empty arrays.
export default class UpcomingBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uptasks: this.props.uptasks,
      uptaskdate: this.props.uptaskdate,

      taskentries: [],
    };

    this.combineTaskInfo = this.combineTaskInfo.bind(this);
  }

  combineTaskInfo() {
    const task = this.state.uptasks.map((task) => {
      return task;
    });
    const taskdate = this.props.uptaskdate;
    // const entry = if (task.id === taskdate.task_id) {
    //   this.setState({
    //     taskentries: [{
    //       task: task.task,
    //       lastcompleted: taskdate.lastcompleted,
    //       help: task.instructions,
    //     }].concat(this.state.taskentries),
    //   });
    // }
    console.log(
      "task",
      task,
      "task dates",
      taskdate,
      "task prop",
      this.state.uptasks,
      "taskdate props",
      this.state.uptaskdate
    );
  }


`> {
>   "uptasks": [
>     {
>       "id": 4,
>       "instructions": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAArcAAAuECAIAAAAHicDwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhe7N15m1VVlif+dEAcAVERxAkQFOdZM9PMrKysrHxq7O7q7uo/+s3ky+gX0FU9VtVT/cvKyszKOZ1RFBEQlRkEQRFxFoff55zvieM14kZwYyBAXF/1eO4+a6+91tpr2jci7j3n888//0ahUCgUCoXCBJzb/b9QKBQKhULhy6guoVAoFAqFwnBUl1AoFAqFQmE4qksoFAqFQqEwHNUlFAqFQqFQGI7qEgqFQqFQKAxHdQmFQqFQKBSGo7qEQqFQKBQKw1FdQqFQKBQKheGoLqFQKBQKhcJwVJdQKBQKhUJhOKpLKBQKhUKhMBzVJRQKhUKhUBiO6hIKhUKhUCgMR3UJhUKhUCgUhqO6hE...",
>       "task": "pull strings from conveyor beaerings"
>     }
>   ],
>   "uptaskdate": [
>     {
>       "lastcompleted": "2024-04-30",
>       "nextdue": "2024-06-19",
>       "specs_sn": 101010,
>       "task_id": 4
>     }
>   ]
> }`

I've tried using the this.props, I've put them into state and tried this.state, the main goal is to map them but it isn't reading the props info.


so it looks like the function was trying to run first. Had to set it inside the function that should run before it , at the end.
So i had to go back one component in the tree, then put my combine function call into the function that is called right before.
getOverTaskInfo() {
const odtaskid = this.state.overdue.map((record) => {
  return record.task_id;
});
const odtaskrec = odtaskid.forEach((record) => {
  axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/Task/${record}`).then((response) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        finaloverdue: [response.data].concat(this.state.finaloverdue),
      },
      () => {
        this.combineOverTaskInfo();
      }
    );
  });
});

}
this way it will run after the props i was looking for showed up in state for the function to use.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
